# Python program starting on start-up?

Tags: windows-7, boot, python

I want to make a python program run on startup and stay running in the backgorund in a manner that would allow me to access it at any time?

I found some articles on how to make it run in the background so that's not much of an issue but I don't know how to make it run in the background?

Basically what I want to do is that I want that program to be a "monitor" that always displays a collection of information that I can access at any time using a hotkey or something. So how can I make that program run at start up?

Comment: it would help if you told us what OS you're running...

Comment: I suppose you could launch it inside of `screen` if you're on a *nix system. You could also have it listen to a socket and interact that way.

Comment: I'm running windows 7

Answer (score 0):

To make python program run in background : `pythonw your_script.py`

You should add this to the following registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`